# H-bonding in o-hydroxybenzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

[image]
Amongst all hydroxybenzoic acids the ortho isomer is most acidic and the major reason is intramolecular H-bonding in the anion.

My question is that isn't the loss of proton destabilising the molecule more than stabilising it as earlier two H-bonds were possible but after deprotonation only one bond remains??

Comment: But how is my question related to ortho effect?

Comment: I think the title is misleading.